# Trouble Compiling PyQt5 Python app with PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I've seen a few posts saying this issue is resolved in the, but I'm still not able to successfully compile with Python 3.6.4, PyQt 5.10.1, and Pyinstaller 3.3.1.

Getting a ton of warnings (like the one below) and the resulting executable isn't working.

```
WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\users\justin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\bearer\qgenericbearer.dll type errors.
```

I tried including the python directory in my command, but no dice. Currently using this command:

```
pyinstaller --paths "C:\Users\Justin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin" "..\main.py"
```

Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: try updating your version of pyinstaller.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on 3.3.1, the latest version, but still getting the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out other missing modules were causing the issue with the .exe. I'm still getting all those api-ms-win errors, but my app runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

`api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`  is part of the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package.

[Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: I installed C++ 2015 (and also have 2017 installed) but still getting those errors and the resulting executable won't launch. Any other ideas why this is happening?                                                                                               


Getting lots of these:


3995 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\justin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe

and tons of these:

16775 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of [........]\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll

Comment: Well, I found out other missing modules were causing the issue with the .exe. I'm still getting all those api-ms-win errors, but my app runs fine.

Comment: I would say try reinstalling [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). I noticed api-ms-xxx.dll's in my Python folder yesterday before I switched over to Linux, so my guess is that maybe reinstalling may help.